# Using precompiled binaries in yesod development

Tags: haskell, ghc, yesod, haskell-stack

Yesod quickstart recommends me that:

```
Follow the installation instructions for stack to get stack.
Create a new scaffolded site: stack new my-project yesod-sqlite && cd my-project
    NOTE: Use stack templates to see other available Yesod scaffoldings.
Install the yesod command line tool: stack install yesod-bin cabal-install --install-ghc
Build libraries: stack build
Launch devel server: stack exec -- yesod devel
View your Yesod site at http://localhost:3000/
```

However `stack install ..` and `stack build` wants to download and compile ~200 packages and build time is unacceptable (about an hour).

On top of that, your app itself isn't compiled until `stack exec`, and it can take some time if I have many TH stuffs like hamlet and persistent.

I think it is preferable to have my stack or cabal download everything as precompiled binaries, and run my dev site via `runhaskell` or `stack exec runhaskell` for minimum compilation time. So here are my two questions:

1. How can I use precompiled binaries for stack and yesod installs?
2. How can I make ghci to reload source after edit while running in interpreted mode? `yesod devel` does that, but it tries to recompile ..

Comment: For what it's worth, now that you have those binaries installed `stack` will reuse them for future installs. Are you expecting to do a lot of from-scratch installing?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Deploying your Webapp](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp) chapter of the Yesod Web Framework Book. In short, there is a deploy manager called Keter that is integrated into `yesod` tool and can be used to deploy compiled apps.